# Moshi Custom field name dynamic

Tags: dynamic, moshi

Is there any possible to define a custom field name dynamicly? I need different field name with different envirnment. But I don`t know how to do with it. Any body can do me a favor, I try to code like following picture. But it doesn`t work obviously.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYauY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
data class Foo(
   @Json(name="xxx")
   private val xxxx: String? = null,
   @Json(name="word")
   private val alternateWord: String? = null,
   )
   {
      val word = xxxx ?: alternateWord // or throw if it's expected
   }
```

This way you can deserialize two different variables at the class level and access them using "word".

Comment: I want generate the value automaticly with different environment, just like the following picture

Comment: Annotation values are used at compile-time, you cannot dynamically generate them. The example I have given uses compile-time values and parsing is done at runtime depending on the JSON node.